# Votes aren't migrated with questions?

Tags: bug, voting, migration

It is about [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210245/why-i-cant-export-the-linux-display) question on unix SE migrated from the SF.

What I did:

1. I voted the question up (on SF).
2. Voted to migrate it to unix SE. It was migrated (my vote was the last needed).
3. Followed the migrated question on the unix SE. Its vote count was also migrated from SF.
4. *But* the up arrow didn't signed that I already voted this question. Thus, I was able to vote it up again.

Currently the question has 2 upvotes from me, but from different sites.

I think, maybe the question owners are perfectly synchronized on question migrations, but its voters aren't.

It is a bug or feature?